# How to parse html and css to understand the layout of the page (java)

Tags: java, translation, html-parsing

i need to find away to parse html and css layout to be able to transform it to to property language that 
understand simple html with inline css on each html element 
how i approach to such task ?

Comment: What do you mean? I only find this about "property language" and that is hardware/software interaction: http://www.thefreelibrary.com/IEEE+Approves+Property+Language+Standard+for+Verification+of+Complex+...-a0136645011
Also, languages are representations and don't understand anything themselves. There would have to be something that understands the language. What does understand mean for you (e.g. being able to render it)?

Comment: sorry 
in house language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read about DOM parsing using Java, with support for parsing HTML documents. One such example is [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/).

Read more into Java HTML DOM parsing, also here is a pretty comprehensive list of available parsers:

http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Comment: as i asked , simple html is no problem , i need to understand somehow 
also css/css2 styleshite also